# CiviCRM failed to upgrade

Tags: upgrade

We are trying to upgrade CiviCRM to 5.67.1 and are hit with an error

```
ALTER TABLE `civicrm_contribution_page` CHANGE `title` `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Contribution Page title. For top of page display' [nativecode=1265 ** Data truncated for column 'title' at row 14]"

mysql> SELECT MAX(LENGTH(title)) FROM `civicrm_contribution_page` WHERE 1;
+--------------------+
| MAX(LENGTH(title)) |
+--------------------+
|                 25 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Not sure what is the issue, Has anyone got similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a record in civicrm_contribution_page with an empty title field.

```
SELECT id, title FROM civicrm_contribution_page WHERE title IS NULL;
```

If you get a list update the title from the UI or run the below query to update the title temporary

```
UPDATE civicrm_contribution_page
SET title = CONCAT('Page-', id)
WHERE title IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep, We have updated the title manually.